# GET Request works with Browser's REST Client but not with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, ntlm

I am trying to get an HTML response after hitting an ASP page. It has NTLM authentication which I tried to resolve using npm-ntlm client. The response is returned from a REST client like postman with NTLM enabled (Auth headers). However, while trying to request the same URL from [npm-ntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntlm-client) in JS, I am receiving the error:

```
SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
```

Example code:

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  username: "user",
  password: "password@#",
  uri: 'https://URL.com',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  agent: false
};
ntlm_req.request(options).then((res)=>{
  console.log("success");
}, (err)=>{
  console.log("err");
});
```

Note: I have tried almost all the methods listed in other answers to fetch a response but unable to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with [httpntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpntlm) by providing parameters in the following way:

```
  httpntlm.get({
    url: url, // complete URL to be fetched
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pswd',
    workstation: 'MachineSerialNo', // host name
    domain: '' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try telling the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) instance of your [ntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntlm-client) call to ignore ssl issues.

Try this:

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  username: "user",
  password: "password@#",
  uri: 'https://URL.com',
  request: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
    // or this:
    // strictSSL : false
  },
  agent: false
};
ntlm_req.request(options).then((res)=>{
  console.log("success");
}, (err)=>{
  console.log("err");
});
```

Looks to me that you almost got it right :)

You only forgot to pass the request's instance options properly ;)

Comment: I tried but it still gives an error: {} , not sure why its not able to fetch info

Comment: could you post the current code and the full output?

Comment: The code is same as what you wrote, error is 401 Unauthorised, I think server side changes are required.

Comment: Well, so i guess your original issue is resolved, now you got another one! Hahaha.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new issue with more information on both client and server side. I'll take a look to try to help for sure! :) best luck!